# Compare 2 Array structs, find unique Element

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, compare

I have a problem here. Below is what I want to achieve:

1. I have 2 array structs (array1 and array2)
2. I want to compare one member which they have in common. Which is ID
3. array 1 has around 6 elements of ID (has duplicates)
4. array 2 has 4 elements of ID
5. I want to find the ID that is contained in array1 but not found in array2.
6. I have tried using a nested for loop, but cant seem to get anywhere..
7. counter = 6, counter2 = 4

code:

```
void add(object array1[10],object2 array2[10],int counter,int counter2)
{
    for (int i=0; i<counter; i++)
   {
        for(int o=0; o<counter2; o++)
       {
            if (array1[i].id != array2[o].id)
            cout<<array1[i].id<<endl;
       }
    }
}
```

the program just prints out all the non duplicates found in array1, and they each repeat at least 3 times,
like:

```
100
100 
100
999
999
999
999
200
200
200
300
300
300
```

But one element in array1 repeats 4 times(999). thats the element I want,and this particular ID is not found at all in array2, but I dont know how to program it. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your concept

- the inner loop will check each element of array1 with each one in array 2 and print value for each mismatch this can be avoided by using a `flag` variable. hence the code will be like:

  `void add(object array1[10],object2 array2[10],int counter,int counter2)
    {
          int flag=0;
          for (int i=0; i<counter; i++)
         {
              flag=0;
              for(int o=0; o<counter2; o++)
               {
                  if (array1[i].id == array2[o].id)
                  flag=1;
               }
              if (flag==0)
              cout<<array1[i]<<endl;
          }
    }`

**For example:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void add(int array1[],int array2[],int counter,int counter2)
{
    int flag=0;
    for (int i=0; i<counter; i++)
   {
       flag=0;
        for(int o=0; o<counter2; o++)
       {
            if (array1[i]==array2[o])
            flag=1;
       }
       if (flag==0)
       cout<<array1[i]<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
  int array1[6]={100,110,120,100,102,100};
  int array2[4]={100,110,120,100};
  add(array1,array2,6,4);
    return 0;
}
```

this will print `102`

Comment: wow! thanks! this totally helped and solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to implement the algorithm yourself or can you use the standard library? If it's the latter, have a look at [set_difference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference). Just keep in mind that the two ranges have to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that array1 = {1, 2} and array2 = {2, 3}.

First iteration of the loop:
array1[0] = 1 & array2[0] = 2 so your program prints 1

Second iteration:
array1[0] = 1 & array2[1] = 3 so your program redundantly prints 1 again.

What you want to do is use a boolean value in the inner loop.  Set the bool to True and then mark it False if you find a match.  After the inner loop finishes, if it is still true then you have found a unique element.